# Error mapping types after updating to abp 2.3.0

Tags: aspnetboilerplate

after updating abp from 1.4.2 to 2.3.0 i got an error while trying to map entity to a Dto

```
 var articles = _articleRepository.GetAll().Where(p => p.ProductId == id);
 var mappedArticles = ObjectMapper.Map<List<ArticleListItemDto>>(articles);
```

it gives me error mapping types, everything was working before and after the update it's not working

also it throw exception for lazy loaded properties only while mapping, if i tried `GetAllIncluding` instead of `GetAll` the mapper is working fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it by adding the below configuration to the connection string.

```
MultipleActiveResultSets=true;
```